# averaging integers in while loop. C language

Tags: c

I am trying to get the averageInt to work properly. As of now If I enter: 10(return key)20(return key)30(return key)40(return key)50(return key)L
the average prints: 10

the answer should be 30. I don't understand how it would return 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
//variable declarations
int minInt = 10, maxInt = 0, averageInt=0, numDivBy7 = 0, numGreat15 = 0;
int userInt = 0, sumOfInt = 0, count = 0;

//prompting user for values
printf("Enter integers (enter a character to terminate): ");



//while loop
while (scanf(" %d",&userInt) == 1 )
{
    count++;
    if (userInt<minInt)
        minInt=userInt;
    if (userInt>maxInt)
        maxInt=userInt;
    sumOfInt =+ userInt;
    averageInt = (double)sumOfInt/count;
    if (userInt%7 == 0)
        numDivBy7++;
    if (userInt > 15)
        numGreat15++;
    printf("Enter another integer (enter a character to terminate): ");
}

if (maxInt == 0 && minInt == 10)
    printf("The user entered no integers\n");
else
{
printf("Min: %.2d\tMax: %.2d\tAverage: %.2d",minInt,maxInt,averageInt);
printf("\nDivisable by 7: %.2d\tGreater than 15: %.2d\n",numDivBy7,numGreat15);
}

//terminate
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As useless as it sounds, answer "How do I check if a user entered a non-digit?" will be *directly* related to "How do I check if a user entered a digit?" Perhaps take a look a ctype.h:isdigit() as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `userInt` in every loop, so you have to put the `scanf` in the `while` loop. And `userInt != char` is not a valid conditional test.

The `scanf` will return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, in your case, when the user input is digit, it will return 1, we can use this as the `while` loop's test.

```
...

userInt = 0;
maxInt = 0;
minInt = (1<<31)-1; //a integer large enough

while( scanf(" %d",&userInt) == 1 )
{
...
}

...
```

Comment: i tried it that way, but getting is userInt being used w/o being initialized.

Comment: @CorySTG, you need to initialize maxInt, minInt with other value. See my code.

Comment: Is it not still initialized from the top, "int userInt, sumOfInt = 0, count = 0;"?

Comment: no, `int userInt` does not init the `userInt`, `int userInt = 0` does

Comment: great! i've got that working, but now my minInt and maxInt are all messed up since they are before the scanf() and I can't put it in the while loop, because they will be over written every iteration.

Comment: @CorySTG, the initialization of `maxInt` and `minInt` is performed before the loop, not in the loop.

Comment: Yes, i know that. How do I get the min and max now without assigning the min with an absurdly large number and the max with a crazy small, so that if one number was entered, chances are those integers would be re-assigned?

Comment: @CorySTG, or just let `max=-1` and `min=-1`, and do `if(max==-1 || num>max) ...`, similar to min

Comment: okay, i've got it working except for the average is messed up. When i enter: 4, 8, 15, 29, 14, 25, 21, E. It prints '03'.

Comment: @CorySTG, `int minInt, maxInt, averageInt`, did you do `averageInt=0`?

Comment: I did "int minInt = 10, maxInt = 0, averageInt=0;" that way at the end of code there is now an, "if (maxInt == 0 && minInt == 10)". so i can print a message that says the user failed to enter an integer

Comment: @CorySTG, I don't get you, why `maxInt==0 && minInt==10`, or update your question pls?

Comment: I updated my code and question.  Thank you very much for stepping me through this. This is a big help.

Comment: @CorySTG, you're welcome. Now that you want a float number, you don't need the `averageInt` to be `int`, right? To print a float with two decimal points, use "%.2f", further, why did you use "%.2d" to print `numDivBy7` and `numGreater15`?

Comment: okay, I changed "int averageInt" to "double averageInt" and did %.2f and it printed the same value. Oh, and the ".2" isn't needed in those integers, wasn't really thinking.

Comment: @CorySTG, `sumOfInt =+ userInt;`? should it be `+=`?

Comment: WoW, That's it!  +9002 internets to you sir!

Comment: internets are equivalent to fantasy bonus points. (souns cool, but, worthless). threw in that "over 9000" reference to dragonballZ if you're a fan of that, heh.   Thanks again for all your help and that hour+ of your life you'll never get back.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your code set up at this moment it reads an integer as a number, rather than a series of characters. From what I can understand of your question this is not what you want.

What you want to use is scanf("%c", &charpointer). This reads one character at a time, and a null ('\0') when the stream ends.

The other part of your question has to do with determining if a given character is a digit. The important thing to keep in mind is that digits are characters, and characters are numbers, so the expression 'a' < 'c' is perfectly valid and true. So any character that fits the boolean expression (c>='0'||c<='9') will evaluate as true if a given character, c, is a numeric digit.

Answer (score 1):

try to declare first your **userInt** then if program detected to be a integer the program will continue, something like this

> //prompting user for values
>
> char = userInt;
>
> printf("Enter integers (enter a character to terminate): ");
>
> scanf(" %c",&userInt);
>
> if(userInt>=0){
>
> continue running program
>
> }else{ end }

Comment: I Tried "while (userInt>=0)". It returned error that averageInt is being used without being initialized. I know that's not because of what I changed, but should that work in the while parameters?

Comment: try to put your parameter inside your while loop